# How to convert a tabularx table into longtable in twocolumn class?

Tags: latex, tabular

I have created a table. I used template of springer which has a \documentclass[twocolumn] class. the table is shown in the following figure:

[image]

my code :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn


%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{cuted}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{upgreek}

%upgreek
%%%%%%%%%%%farm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}



\usepackage{booktabs,array,enumitem,ragged2e}

\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{%
  \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{%
  leftmargin = *               ,
  label      = \textbullet     ,
  nosep                        ,
  before     = \tablistcommand ,
  after      = \tablistcommand
}
%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}


\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut
\usepackage{longtable}










        \begin{document}
        
        \begin{table} [htp]
        
            \setcellgapes{2pt}
            \centering
            \scriptsize
          \makegapedcells
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
        {| p{0.007\textwidth} | p{0.068\textwidth} | p{0.1535\textwidth} | p{0.1535\textwidth}  |  }  
          \hline
          
        %%%%  
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{0.1\textwidth}|}{  A} & B & C\\ \hline
        %%%%
        
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
          & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
        \\ \hline 
        
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
          & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
        \\ \hline 
        
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
          & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
        \\ \hline 
        
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
          & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
        \\ \hline 
        
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
          & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
        \\ \hline 
        
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
          & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
        \\ \hline 
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
          & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
        \\ \hline 
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
          & 
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        
        \\ \hline 
          \end{tabularx}
          \end{table}
        
        
        \bibliographystyle{spmpsci_copy}
        \bibliography{Bibliography}
        
        
        
        \end{document}
```

How to active the auto-break of my table, i mean that I want to replace automatic the part of the table which penetrates the limits to next page as shown in that picture :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `xtabular` from the `xtab` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

{%
  \scriptsize
  \setcellgapes{4pt}
  \makegapedcells 
  \begin{xtabular}{|p{0.068\textwidth}|p{0.167\textwidth}|p{0.167\textwidth}|} 
    \hline
    A & B & C\\ \hline
    MADM &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\ \hline 
    MADM &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\ \hline  
    MADM &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\ \hline 
    MADM &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\ \hline 
    MADM &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\ \hline 
    MADM &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\ \hline 
    MADM &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\ \hline 
    MADM &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\ \hline 
  \end{xtabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suffered from that problem : ! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\linewidth): `c' used.See the array package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{xtabular}{\linewidth}

Comment: @Brm-Covißio Try with the syntax from my answer, e.g. no `\linewidth` (it does not make any sense in your code anyway as you did not use a `X` column)

Comment: thank you very much but you forget the following instructions :     \setcellgapes{2pt}, \centering, \scriptsize, \makegapedcells

Comment: @Brm-Covißio `\centering` makes no sense if the table already fills the whole column